# kotlin notebook dataframe: How to create navigable hyperlink?

Tags: dataframe, kotlin, jupyter-notebook

I have a kotlin notebook with the following cell

```
%use dataframe
val engines = dataFrameOf("name", "link")("google", "https://google.com", "bing", "https://bing.com")
engines
```

Running the cell renders a dataframe showing the URLs, but they are not clickable.
How can I generate a hyperlink?